# Electron : using showOpenDialog allows files to be chosen on Linux & Win10 but why can't I choose file on MacOS?

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, openfiledialog

I'm using the following code (with great success on Linux and Win10) to select a file (and ultimately read its contents).

This is in my main.js and pops up a dialog on Linux and Win10 and allows me to choose a file.

```
ipc.on('open-file-dialog', function (event) {
  dialog.showOpenDialog({
    properties: ['openFiles'],
    defaultPath: specialFoldersPath,

  }, function (files) {
    if (files) event.sender.send('selected-file', files)
  })
})
```

The code pops up the file open dialog on MacOS too, however, on my Mac Mini running MacOS Mojave v10.14.6 I see the following:

[image: Mac open file dialog]

Notice that I *can* select a folder but I cannot select any files (they are greyed out and disabled).

I've examined the options at https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog but I don't see any additional option that needs to be set for MacOS to allow files to be selected.  Do you know why this is occurring?

**Note**: As I was writing this up, I noticed something with the code that ended up being the solution.  However, since SO says you can post an answer a question that hasn't been asked and because this is an interesting problem I decided to post and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After staring at the [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog) for quite a while I noticed the problem.
It was very subtle.  Here's the important part from the documentation:
[image: docs say...]

Oops! The properties value is `openFile` not openFile**s**.

The **red herring** was the fact that this *did work properly* (with the wrong property value) on Linux and Win10.

Here is the fixed code:

```
ipc.on('open-file-dialog', function (event) {
  dialog.showOpenDialog({
    properties: ['openFile'],
    defaultPath: specialFoldersPath,

  }, function (files) {
    if (files) event.sender.send('selected-file', files)
  })
})
```